# int is not iterable in while loop

Tags: python, integer

```
def remove_all_before(items: list, border: int) -> Iterable:
    i = 0
    solve = items
    while True:
        if items[i] == border:
            return solve
            break
        else:
            solve = solve.pop(i)
            i = i + 1
```

Error:  'int' object is not iterable
if i remove  solve = solve.pop(i) everything fine
Whats wrong?

Comment: what is in your list? quick fix is to str(items)

Comment: This `solve.pop(i)` returns the popped item, not the modified list. So the first time you call it, `solve` is not a list anymore, but the integer that was popped from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pop()` method removes the item at the given index from the list and returns the removed item.

Since, you assign it back to the `solve` which is supposed to be a list, you get the error when you try to access it by index with `items[i]`.

Change this:

```
solve = solve.pop(i)
```

to something like:

```
poppedElement = solve.pop(i)
```

Comment: Thx, i thought pop returns list without element

Comment: Glad to be of help! Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark @B0nhart.